# How to disable(turn off) android device wifi in appium - AndroidDriver programmatically while test scripts is running?

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I want to turn off wifi in any android device programmatically in my testscript using appium - AndroidDriver to check network unplug scenarios...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The methods in previous answers have been deprecated. Please use these methods to manipulate WiFi connection:

```
 public void WifiOn() {
    ConnectionState state = driver.setConnection(new ConnectionStateBuilder().withWiFiEnabled().build());
    Assert.assertTrue(state.isWiFiEnabled(), "Wifi is not switched on");
    logger.LogTestInfo("WiFi turned on");
}
public void WifiOff() {
    ConnectionState state = driver.setConnection(new ConnectionStateBuilder().withWiFiDisabled().build());
    Assert.assertFalse(state.isWiFiEnabled(), "Wifi is not switched off");
    logger.LogTestInfo("WiFi turned off");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Appium API version 4.0.0 and greater use the following:

```
AndroidDriver driver;

//turn off all connections 

driver.setConnection(Connection.NONE);
assertEquals(Connection.All, driver.getConnection());

//Turn on data and Wifi
driver.setConnection(Connection.ALL);
assertEquals(Connection.All, driver.getConnection());

//Turn just Wifi on
driver.setConnection(Connection.WIFI);
assertEquals(Connection.WIFI, driver.getConnection());
```

Comment: Hi Romil,                                                                                                                                           i tried with driver.setConnection(Connection.NONE), but wifi is not getting disable, showing following error                                                              org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: undefined status object for driver.setConnection(Connection.NONE). Am using appium              java-client-4.1.1, android version-5.1.1 and cyanogen OS . Please help me

Comment: Hi, download Apache Commons Lang » 3.1. Link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.1  Add this external jar to your project. This should solve your issue.

Comment: I tried above code but it do not display NONE,ALL and WIFI as option with Connection.

Comment: Please see the new answer.